# Cordova Custom-URL-scheme plugin not working in iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, git, cordova

I'm trying to use the [Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) in my Ionic Application but it's not working. I am using:

Cordova-iOS Version: **3.8.0**

Ionic Version: **1.4.5**

Xcode Version: **4.2**

[BitBucket Repo](https://bitbucket.org/asthadevteam/customurl/src/0be419c9832e08261afd155616c3f959910d4995?at=master)

I've installed the plugin using cordova cli. In the app.js of my application I've placed the *handleOpenURL* function in the bottom. Now if I try to open the application from another app using he following code, it doesn't work.

```
<button onclick="window.open('MyGreatApp://', '_system')">Open the other app</button>
```

or

```
<a href="MyGreatApp://">Open the other app</a>
```

I also tried changing the plugin.xml of the Custom URL plugin. But not working.  Need help about this.

Answer (score 0):

It might be about upper-case usage. It says use only lowercase letters for scheme name (and some other rules) here:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme#4-url-scheme-hints

And while installing plugin you should give scheme as variable like this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=mygreatapp
```

or if you already installed it, you can set variable in your `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="~4.2.0">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="mygreatapp" />
</plugin>
```